# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, database, wordpress, mysqli

I have a very simple script which is designed to test the speed of the database connected to my WordPress site -

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to view the page I am presented with the error below -

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/carterhutch/public_html/test-database-connection.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/carterhutch/public_html/test-database-connection.php on line 10

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? I have a feeling the issue is to do with not being able to connect to the database server, unfortunately I am new to back-end and database management so haven't a clur how to resolve it. Do I need to add the file to a specific folder within the WordPress setup or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like the server is not reachable, that's nothing about putting files into a folder or another or anything else. Are you sure that your MySQL server is available under the given servername?

Comment: Your server not connected. Your server name is incorrect $servername = "servername"; Also syntax mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

Comment: try `$servername = 'localhost';`

Comment: Please update if $servername = 'localhost' or some other correct server name resolve your issue.

Comment: @Akintunde Can you send me some example where we can make connection separately from database in MySqli. Want to learn a bit.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I have tried using 'localhost' and that doesn't work. I am a bit confused as to which information I need to use. Can I use the ftp login details, or database login details, or something different? I am able to access the server through WHM and phpMyAdmin so could I use the login details for these? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: I have tried every combination of username/password I can think of but still seeing the issue. Assuming I have the correct login details could this isse be caused by something else?

Comment: Issue resolved! The variable names obviously confused me. I was adding the server login details rather than the database login details. Stupid, I know. I also used localhost as the server name which did the trick. Thanks to all that responded